# Very Long Form in modal box?

Tags: usability, forms, modal-windows

I have long form around 25 form fields in web application and it covers 2 whole page. currently it is showing in the same page and cancelling the form goes back to main page. How much lengthy a form is good for modal box?

Comment: I guess you need to simplify further. You mean to ask that the form is in a modal dialog box? What is your use case to have such a big form on popup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modal boxes are helpful for quick tasks or small notices where it is too cumbersome to load a new screen, and the user will want to return to the main screen after processing the modal. It's sometimes okay for modals to overflow a window (see pinterest for example).

The form you are describing seems like the opposite of this situation:

- It has a lot of fields
- It's large
- It requires a lot of user attention

If your Web app needs to be mobile friendly, then I would NOT use a modal because a panel or page is a much better format for such an involved form.

For a Web audience I would still strongly advise against a modal because the modal background can be distracting, the user may dismiss the form by mistake, and you may get a lot of form abandonment. But visually it's more possible to make it work in a web-only context, even if it's really not a good idea.